# How to use AJAX to call php file from javascript file

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I want to call php file from javascript, and this php file will update `id=1`

like this way:

javascript:

```
 if(lastTemp >= document.getElementById("TempSet").value){

   var jsonData2 =$.ajax({
    url: "setpp.php",
    dataType: "json",
    async: false
    }).responseText;
    var obj2 = JSON.parse(jsonData2);
    console.log(obj2);
} 
else {
}
```

php file:

```
 <?php

 $DATABASE_HOST = 'localhost';
 $DATABASE_USER = 'use';
 $DATABASE_PASS = 'pass';
 $DATABASE_NAME = 'database';
 // Try and connect using the info above.
 $db = mysqli_connect($DATABASE_HOST, $DATABASE_USER, $DATABASE_PASS,                          
 $DATABASE_NAME);
 if (!$db){

die("Connection Failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());

      }


    $db_update = "UPDATE setpoint_control SET status='ON' WHERE id=1";

    $result = mysqli_query($db, $db_update);

      ?>

       <?php 
        $data = array(); 
       if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
           while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        array_push($data, $row['status']); 
           }   
       }
           echo json_encode($data); 

        ?>
```

the code is executed and the status in database table is changed but I got error in console : `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 4 column 2 of the JSON data`

How can I solve this issue which I think I need to rewrite `json_encode` but I don't know how?

Comment: what is in the response? Try `console.log(jsonData2)` on the line after you've defined it, to see what it is. (And also, not related to this question, but please don't do synchronous Ajax requests.)

Comment: Try using add_slashes around your json_encode

Comment: when I removed `var obj2 = JSON.parse(jsonData2);` `console.log(obj2);` it works without error~ what could be the reason for that?

Comment: @M.Saeed that's because the original error is to do with the `JSON.parse` statement, resulting from the response from the PHP being not valid JSON. There could be a number of reasons for that, and I asked to see the actual response (which you can easily log) in order to get a better idea as to what it might be.

Comment: @RobinZigmond after did `console.log(jsonData2)` I got this in the console 

``<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\test\climate\setpp.php</b> on line <b>26</b><br />
[]``

Comment: Right, so that's one of the scenarios I considered likely. You've got a PHP warning, which is coming up as HTML. The easy fix is to turn `display_errors` off in your php.ini - but you should probably fix the cause of the warning. [which appears to be to do with the UPDATE query failing. Check your database to confirm this]

Comment: @RobinZigmond yes I am sure my mistake is int PHP file regarding UPDATE query specially in json_encode area! but don't know how to correct it! :)

Answer (score -1):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    url: 'setpp.php',
    success: function (response) {
        $.each(response, function(i, item) {
            alert(item);
        });     
    },
    error: function () {
      alert("error");
    },
});
```

example php answer `setpp.php`

```php
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        array_push($data, $row['status']);
    }
    die(json_encode($data));
} else {
    $answer = array(
         'No Records'
    );
    die(json_encode($answer));
}
```

I think the problem is the value returned by `setpp.php`.

remember to `die()`, otherwise the php answer will not be correct

Comment: [Quentin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19068/quentin) why you downvote and removed your answer? :)

Comment: it gave me `error` but the json in `setpp,php` executed! I couldn't understand it

Comment: @M.Saeed im improved my answer above. Please check it now.

Comment: still give me error! in `setpp.php` I made it like this:
`$data = array(); 
 if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
      array_push($data, $row['status']); 
      }
echo json_encode($data); 
      
     }

die(json_encode($data));`

Comment: improved it again, you didnt die() :)

Comment: Once you just `echo` your data, the script is still executing and mess up the answer data.

Comment: Just tested it on my server [`http://g3ck.com/test.html`](http://g3ck.com/test.html). Working just fine... the problem need to be somewhere else...

Comment: this doesn't make sense *remember to die()*??

Comment: just remember to use `die()` function... whats wrong [Junius L.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3858806/junius-l)?

Comment: Strange for me After made it like this I got response 1 without error `<?php

$DATABASE_HOST = 'mysite.com';
$DATABASE_USER = 'user';
$DATABASE_PASS = '12345';
$DATABASE_NAME = 'dbname';
// Try and connect using the info above.
$db = mysqli_connect($DATABASE_HOST, $DATABASE_USER, $DATABASE_PASS, $DATABASE_NAME);
if (!$db){

 die("Connection Failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());

}


     $db_update = "UPDATE setpoint_control SET status='on' WHERE id=1";
  
     $result = mysqli_query($db, $db_update);
        echo($result);
?>`